# Reverse engineering to get answers

Tags: reverse-engineering

So I've spent the last few days looking for a way to create a simple image drawing app with wxPython, and I think the key to doing just that is understanding how to use Device Contexts. The problem is that the wxPython demo program doesn't demonstrate DCs, and the docs for both wxPython and wxWidgets don't explain as much as I'd like to know so I've decided to try and 'reverse engineer' an existing app to see how its done.

The first problem I have is that I don't know of any drawing apps written in wxPython (or any written in Python for that matter o.o), and the second is I don't know how I'd go about doing it. Am I right in saying that I'm going to need a copy of an application's Python source and something like Winpdb? What do professional programmers do when they find themselves in a situation like mine, needing answers that the docs don't provide?

Comment: from what I know, Python is a script language, so the program usually IS the source

Answer (score 1):

If you need to understand the concepts, but the docs don't cut it, it's worth it to look at docs for similar APIs.  In the case of drawing contexts, there are a lot of similar APIs in other languages.  Java has Swing for instance.

Reverse engineering is easier in tools that aren't big event-driven GUI things.  The converse is that event-driven GUI things tend to copy each other, so you only need to figure them out once or twice before they all make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET world, I have [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) as indispensable tool.

In my company, we use to program [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/) websites. There are many "gotchas" we just figure out by reverse engineering that product assemblies, exactly because documentation is plain wrong, just missing or simply doesn't exists.